# How can we generate more traffic for the site?

Tags: discussion

Question's in the title: what can we do to generate more traffic for ELL? Taking a look at our [area51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners), everything is doing well except for visits per day. The stat explanation says:

> 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work.

We've got a whopping 258 visits/day, and this stat has been pretty much the same every time I've checked it during the public beta.  We're hovering around 250, which is only *half* of the benchmark to start worrying.

I think we're doing really well with the community we're building, but we really aren't getting many new active users, and clearly we're not getting out-of-network visits very often.  The area51 page also says:

> A great site benefits people outside the community. Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines.

So, keeping these things in mind, any ideas for things we can do to increase traffic for the site?  I don't want the community to stagnate, I want us to grow!

Comment: You're just splitting up the information. Saying the question was asked 30 days ago is not sufficient reason to (re)create an identical conversation. If you have another more-specific premise under which to discuss specific options, then please do ask much more specific questions.... but this post should be merged with the duplicate discussion on this generic discussion.